# How to convert..for eg: abc(input) to fdg(output) when u give the numbers (524) as a second input?

Tags: python-3.x

How can i add the given numbers(524) to the input(abc) and obtain the required output(fdg)?
i.e; i wanted to add 5 to 'a' and obtain 'f' as the output,add 2 to 'b' and get 'd' as output and so on even for numbers and special characters.
2 eg..input-(0ghk) and (7351)..The output should be  (7jml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use zip() (https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
start = "abc"
number = 524
result = ""
for letter, i in zip(start, str(number)):
    result += chr(ord(letter) + int(i))
print(result)
```

Which gives you:

```
fdg
```

Answer (score -1):

1. create a new string variable : `result = ""`
2. for v in theVaribleYouWantToConvert:
3. get the ascii code by using ord()
4. add the good number
5. get the char value (something like chr(ord(v) + number)
   to get the right number, you should use int()

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I got the first 3 steps and the last step,but i wanted to know how to add a specified number with the specified alphabet.If i give the number 673,the first alphabet should add with 6,and 2nd alphabet with 7,if i use one more for loop for the numbers its adding a single number to all the alphabets and i am getting an output like 3*3=9 alphabets as a result,but i just wanted 3 alphabets.@laenNoCode

Comment: you can do it in 2 different ways : first using modulus10 and divide by 10 (you iterate through your char list in reverse order, then num%10 = how much you should add, but then each step you divide by ten) other way to do it is to iterate on str(num) so it will take each number, then use int() of that value to know how much you shoud add

Comment: I remembered the modulo operator only after u wrote that ..thanks and it was helpful.